# Postman AssertionError: expected 10137 to equal 10093

Tags: testing, postman, assertion, manual-testing, automation-testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSqsn.png)Whenever I try to edit the task the test fails
Test code:

```js
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Gallery has correct id", function(){
pm.expect(pm.environment.get("boardId")).to.equals(jsonData.board_id)})
```

Test result:

Fail: Gallery has correct id | AssertionError: expected 10140 to equal 10093

I'm trying to check if `boardid` is equal to the response from `board_id`, but I just don't understand why it's throwing me a number 10093. Because whenever I create a task it responds to me with 10140 but when I edit the task it responds to me with `board_id` 10093
Hope someone can help me! Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbNHF.png)

Comment: Could you provide more info, i.e. response and screenshot of Environment?

Comment: yep I added the images

Comment: it seems you added wrong images.